# Plain XeTeX cyrillic font

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex

I am using XeTeX and love it very much.
When I use helatex, I have no problems at all. 
But I want to try do it «True Way»: plainTex.
XeTeX takes all annoyance with unicode from me, but sample like this

```
\font\foo=bar
\foo
{\bf Привет, мир!}


{Jellios}
\bye
```

fails, because font have not cyrillic symbols. 
So, my question is example of font(with tfm file), that have cyrillic symbols.

My system is Arch GNU/Linux.

Comment: You basically have to reproduce the working of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and of `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}`. Not impossible, but quite a project.

Comment: Why do you want to use a font with tfm with xetex? Why don't you use simply a system font with cyrillic symbols? And why do you want to restrict yourself to an old and plain system when newer and better systems like latex or context exist?

Comment: @Ulrike: the word "restrict" is sooooo out of place in your comment! ;-)

Comment: @Ulrike: Because I want to combine deep understanding that can be digged in Knuth' book and UTF-8 convinence.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work with the following settings:

Created file in WIN1251 encoding with the following contents:

```
\font\rm=larm1095
\font\bf=labx1095

\beginsection
Что сказал медведь

\rm

Выпей водки и сыграй на балалайке, Иван

\bye
```

Compiled it with pdftex.

I used this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51891) by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) in the neighbour thread to determine the font, which is used by latex, so all credits go to him.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Plain `\bf` macro calls `\fam6` (change math family) and also `\tenbf` (the actual font name), which is (**by default**) the Computer Modern tfm ten point bold font. So you could do (note, you said your **example** uses tfm, my **example** uses OpenType font which came with OSX, because you explicitly mentioned XeTeX and Unicode):

```
\font\tenrm="Baskerville"
\font\tenbf="Baskerville/B"
\rm

{\bf Привет, мир!}

Jellios
\bye
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @egreg: what do you mean? Does my edit clear things up?

Comment: The question deals with "classical" TeX fonts (with tfm file).

Comment: @egreg: I understand the question differently.

Comment: XeTeX dont find tfm file for Baskervillie so by analogy 
I tried use `DejaVu Sans Mono`, that works perfectly for xelatex. Strangely, I get no cyrillic symbols.

Comment: @illusionoflife: XeTeX doesn't need tfm files for OpenType fonts, it can use the system fonts directly. What fonts are available on your OS depends on the system you use. I use Mac OS X, and Baskerville comes with that. A common font which comes with both Windows and OS X is Arial which includes cyrillic. But depending on what you're doing, it may well not be that great a font all things considered. Maybe you could try out [Charis SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=CharisSILfont) and see if you like it? Just install it on your OS and then you can use it in XeTeX.

Comment: @illusionoflife: also, DejaVu Sans Mono (OTF) should work just by `\font\blah="DejaVu Sans Mono" \blah Привет\bye`.