# Cyrillic letters and Russian hyphenation in Plain XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex, format-files

What is the simplest method to tell XeTeX (not XeLaTeX) to use a font with Cyrillic letters and to apply Russian hyphenation rules?

Ideally i would like to not have to specify anything in the source files, but to get new commands `rxetex` and `ramsxetex` to compile sources in Russian.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the preloaded cm text fonts with Unicode aware ones, and use them in your documents. Asumming that you have a working XeTeX installation, try the following:

1. Install the OTF version of the cm-unicode set of fonts into your system. You can download them from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-unicode).
2. Run `fc-cache` on a terminal to update the font database cache.
3. Copy the following code into `cmunfonts.tex`, and input this file at the beginning of your document.

```
\message{cm unicode fonts!}

\font\tenrm="[cmunrm]" at 10 pt% roman text
\font\sevenrm="[cmunrm]" at 7pt
\font\fiverm="[cmunrm]" at 5pt

\font\tenbf="[cmunbx]" at 10pt % boldface extended
\font\sevenbf="[cmunbx]" at 7pt
\font\fivebf="[cmunbx]" at 5pt

\font\tentt="[cmunbtl]" at 10pt % typewriter

\font\tensl="[cmunsl]" at 10pt % slanted roman

\font\tenit="[cmunti]" at 10pt % text italic

\endinput
```

Now try to `xetex yourfile` and see if that works.

In general, you will need to substitute the default 7bit cm text fonts with unicode text fonts in all your font definitions in your input files.

Now, to use russian hyphenation you need to use a format different than plain.fmt: that's untouchable. I recommend to you to install [hyplain](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyplain), the [russian loader](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/hyph-utf8/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-ru.tex), and the [hyphenation patterns](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/hyph-utf8/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-ru.tex) (from [`hyph-utf8` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyph-utf8)) from CTAN; check the documentation for hyplain (it's two pages), and at the appropriate place in the `hylang.tex` file, add russian as follows:

```
\input unicode-letters
\definelanguage{ru}{RU}{loadhyph-ru}
\refinelanguage{ru}{RU}{\hyphenmins{2}{2}\frenchspacing}{\nonfrenchspacing}
\addalias\russ{ru}{RU}
```

Make the format running `xetex -ini *hyplain`, and call `xetex ^&hyplain yourfile` and it will compile with cyrillic and russian hyphenation.

Then you can make a batch file or bash script `rxetex` to include the line `xetex ^&hyplain %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6` to run your russian enabled xetex in a prompt.

I'm sorry, but I can see no way you may bypass the process of learning how to make a format.

Comment: Nice to see that there are people using `hyplain`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Do you think is it possible to dispense with the \preloaded fonts in the code above? —And yes, hyplain is a nice hack!

Comment: There's no need to define those `\preloaded` fonts: you can't store OpenType fonts in the format anyway, so you don't save time by defining those fonts: indeed, you lose some because you load fonts that probably you won't use.

Comment: Make sure you convert your input files to utf8 before trying to compile them. Files encoded in cp1251 will likely choke xetex.

Comment: `xetex myfile` does not work, i get `! Internal error: bad native font flag in 'map_char_to_glyph'`.  The error has to do with `\bar` command in math mode and with `amsppt` AMSTeX package -- if i remove one or the other, there is no error.

Comment: It also compiles if i remove `\input cmunfonts.tex`.

Comment: without more specific information, it may be hard to debug your file. Besides providing a snippet of code which triggers the error (the required Minimal Working Example), I just want to point out that amsppt.sty loads even more fonts, and that you also need to substitute the call for those extra cm text fonts with their cmu counterparts.

Comment: I think this may be the same problem: http://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/89/

Comment: There is also a [question about it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63244/internal-error-bad-native-font-flag-xelatex-fontspec-newtxmath-libertine).

Comment: Ok, if i want to patch `amsppt.sty`, could you tell me please, what to use instead of, for example, `cmcsc10`?  I tried `cmuncsc10`, but it does not exist.  Same problem with `cmti7`, etc.

Comment: You stumbled upon a bug in the engine! Having read your references, the source, as I suspected, comes from several attempts at mixing OpenType and tfm fonts. Try to work around it using cmcyr and sticking to pdftex and [either win1251](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180094/non-latin-characters-with-plain-tex/251052#251052) or [encTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248899/easy-method-to-activate-cyrplain-package-cyrtex), as suggested elsewhere.

Comment: I am afraid the other proposed solutions may not quite work without patching `amsppt.sty` anyway.  At least the README of `cyrplain` package says to patch it. (Some instructions there are confusing, because i didn't find, for example, a definition of `\fontprefix` in `cyrtex.cfg`, and patching `amsppt.sty` uses this command).  If i patch `amsppt.sty` to use unicode encoded fonts with all the glyphs i need, then maybe XeTeX will work for me.

Comment: I've posted a separate [question about patching `amsppt.sty`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251883).

Comment: If you see the code above, you'll notice that some fonts are loaded `\sevenrm="whatever" at 7pt`. That order "fakes" a 7pt font otherwise nonexistent—not all unicode fonts are available at all sizes. Try to do the same with the fonts loaded with amsppt.sty. —Having said that, I have to warn you that the bug in XeTeX is triggered by the attempt to load otf and tfm fonts together, so you may stumble on the same stone after all. Moreover, you don't need to patch amsppt.sty; it is enough to load the font substitutions from a cmcyrppt.sty file, for instance.