# How to replace CM fonts with ones compatible with XeTeX (in amsppt.sty)?

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex, amstex

I would like to try to patch `amsppt.sty` AMSTeX style file to make it
usable with XeTeX and non-Latin languages (Cyrillic).  It looks like i need
to replace the following CM fonts or font families with Unicode aware ones :
`cmcsc10`, `cmti7`, `cmr8`, `cmr6`, `cmmi8`, `cmmi6`, `cmsy8`, `cmsy6`, `cmbx8`, `cmbx6`, `cmti8`, `cmsl8`, `cmtt8`, `cmcsc10`, `cmex10`, `cmex10`, `cmmibfam`, `cmmib`, `cmbsyfam`, `cmbsy`, `cmcsc8`, `cmex8`, `cmex7`.

Whis ones can i use instead, and where can i get them?

Another part of this question is how to use new fonts in `amsppt.sty`.  The lines where the fonts are selected look like this:

```
\font@\sevenit=cmti7 \relax
```

Comment: Did you try `cm-unicode`?

Comment: I tried, assuming that `cmcsc10` would be called `cmuncsc10`, `cmti7` would be called `cmunti7`, etc., but such fonts do not exist in `cm-unicode` or are named differently.

Comment: Cm-unicode has no more font files  per size, e.g. you have a `cmunti.otf` file only. As for `cmcsc`, I don't know if it has been converted (its only version 0.7). For now it seems small caps are obtained by scaling uppercase letters. Why don't you use the Latin Modern fonts, which are very close to Computer Modern, and are much more complete? They're the default for `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: It was suggested to me to use `cm-unicode` in an [answer to my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249446/37291).  I will try to see how to use Latin Modern. I hope i will find the ones that contain Cyrillics.

Comment: Could you tell me, please, how Latin Modern fonts with Cyrillics are called, and which package they are in?

Comment: Maybe use Latin Modern as a base with `cm-unicode` for Cyrillics? Loading `fontspec` will enable Latin Modern as default.

Comment: `fontspec` seems to be a LaTeX/XeLaTeX package, how to load it in plain XeTeX?

Comment: Do you plan to use Cyrillic letters in formulas?

Comment: No, i there shouldn't be any.  (There can be Cyrillic text in formulas, but i guess this is a different story.)

Answer (score 2):

I prepared a file `amspptfont.tex` with the following contents

```
\chardef\atfontcatcode=\catcode`\@
\catcode`@=11

% the plain fonts
\font@\tenrm="[cmunrm]" at 10pt
\font@\sevenrm="[cmunrm]" at 7pt
\font@\fiverm="[cmunrm]" at 5pt

\font@\tenbf="[cmunbx]" at 10pt
\font@\sevenbf="[cmunbx]" at 7pt
\font@\fivebf="[cmunbx]" at 5pt

\font@\tentt="[cmuntt]" at 10pt

\font@\tensl="[cmunsl]" at 10pt

\font@\tenit="[cmunti]" at 10pt

% the amsppt fonts
\font@\tensmc="[cmunrm]:+smcp" at 10pt \relax
\font@\sevenit="[cmunti]" \relax
\font@\eightrm="[cmunrm]" at 8pt \relax
\font@\sixrm="[cmunrm]" at 6pt \relax
\font@\eightbf="[cmunbx]" at 8pt \relax
\font@\sixbf="[cmunbx]" at 6pt \relax
\font@\eightit="[cmunti]" at 8pt \relax
\font@\eightsl="[cmunsl]" at 8pt \relax
\font@\eighttt="[cmuntt]" at 8pt \relax
\font@\eightsmc="[cmunrm]:+smcp" at 8pt \relax

\catcode`@=\atfontcatcode
```

Then the following test file

```
\input amstex
\documentstyle{amsppt}
\input amspptfont

\document

Добро пожаловать в русский Викисловарь — многофункциональный многоязычный словарь и тезаурус, 
в обсуждении и пополнении которого может участвовать каждый.

\proclaim{Proposition 2.5} Let $S_1,\dots,S_m$ be the components
of a $J$-holomorphic cusp-curve $S$ and suppose that each
component $S_i$ is \rom(a multiple covering of\rom) a regular
curve and that Assumption \rom{(1.4a)} is satisfied. \dots
\endproclaim

\define\test#1{%
  {\tt\string#1}{#1 Test of the font}\par
}

\test\tenrm
\test\sevenrm
\test\fiverm

\test\tenbf
\test\sevenbf
\test\fivebf

\test\tentt

\test\tensl

\test\tenit

\test\tensmc
\test\sevenit
\test\eightrm
\test\sixrm
\test\eightbf
\test\sixbf
\test\eightit
\test\eightsl
\test\eighttt
\test\eightsmc

\enddocument
```

produces the following output

[image]

I didn't even try math symbol fonts, which would require very extensive work with Latin Modern Math.

Comment: Thanks, i will see if this example can help me to move on. Спасибо :).

Comment: You may add `\uselanguage{russian}` somewhere in your example to enable hyphenation.

Comment: If you add $\bar A$ to your example, there will be an error.  It seems to be [this bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/89/), discussed also [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63244).

Comment: @Alexey Sorry, but it seems that the bug is still there. On the other hand, if I add `\input luaotfload.sty` at the beginning and run `luatex`, there's no error, but no bar accent either. `:-(`

Comment: By the way, what does `\font@` mean? Why is it not `\font`?

Comment: @Alexey It has to do with `\syntax`: `\font@` registers the font selection command for being set equal to `\dummy` if only syntax check is desired.

Comment: To try to hack this, how can i inspect the default value of `\font@\somefont`?

Comment: @Alexey Not sure to understand.

Comment: I am trying to experiment with different setups. For example, i see that `amsppt`, `cmunrm`, and `$\bar A$` produce the error only when used all together. Any two of them work without errors (but not necessarily displaying Cyrillics). I would like to see how, for example, `\tenrm` is defined if i did not define it myself.

Comment: @Alexey `\tenrm` is in `plain.tex` and is `cmr10`. To inspect what external file a symbolic font name refers to, say `\expandafter\show\the\font` in a test document.

Comment: How can i inspect it to be sure? Doesn't it depend on whether i use XeTeX or Plain TeX?  I would like to also inspect the default math fonts if i do not use `amsppt`.

Comment: Ah, ok, i'll try `\expandafter\show\the\font`.

Comment: @Alexey `\show\tenrm` would output `\tenrm=select font cmr10`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25425/discussion-between-alexey-and-egreg).