# How to use plain XeTeX for emoji and words of non-English alphabet?

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex

I am trying to create documents with emojis and words of non-English alphabet (Farsi, Chinese, Korean etc), but I heard that plain TeX does not support this, but plain XeTeX does offer support. However, when I type in these characters, the output PDF is blank, so I don't know if I am missing a package or something else. Can someone give a Hello World demo?

P.S. I am only interested in using Plain XeTeX or Plain TeX (if there's some supporting package).

Comment: Plain XeTeX still uses the standard CM fonts, which are 7bit, OT1 encoded: to add more glyphs you need to set up unicode fonts, or something like that. Have you tried?

Comment: @jarnosz I don't know how to do that.

Comment: you do have the unicode font you want to use in your system, correct?

Comment: Yes, I think those fonts are automatically installed on my computer, just the way I usually type them in say, google search

Comment: my first hunch is that your question might be a duplicate. search for "Plain XeTeX font installation" on this website, and see if there is an answer to your question. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249357/cyrillic-letters-and-russian-hyphenation-in-plain-xetex) in particular.