# What is the equivalent of \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} in plain TeX?

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, font-encodings

I have inherited a semi-small TeX project in which I, after syncing across various computers and OS'es, had some problems with encodings of special characters like `åäö`.

My initial approach for fixing this was to convert everything to UTF-8 (using the `iconv` utility on Ubuntu), which made all the weird incorrect replacement characters disappear. However, the special characters still don't show up.

If this was LaTeX, I'd do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but that doesn't work here because I compile with `pdftex`.

What do I do instead?

Comment: Is `pdftex` utf8 agnostic? You probably need `xetex` or `luatex` **and** you have to specify a font that supports these chars. BTW: interesting question.

Comment: There is no specific encoding support in plain, just load a T1 (8t) encoded font using \font.

Comment: Are you sure you want UTF8 it would be _much_ easier to handle latin 1 in plain TeX.

Comment: So, are you using pdftex with utf8 encoded files?

Answer (score 17):

At first you don't need an equivalent for fontenc but for inputenc. You should (like inputenc) make the non-ascii chars active and map them to suitable commands. E.g. in an 8-bit encoded file you could do something like this:

```
%OT1-encoded font
\catcode`\ä=13
\defä{\"a}

Räuber
\bye
```

[image]

When using a T1-encoded font life is a bit easier, as a lot of chars are already in "the correct position". So the catcode changes are often not really needed, but as you can see with the ß some chars can be wrong if you don't add a definition

```
%Use a T1-encoded font:
%\catcode`\ä=13
%\defä{\char"E4}
% \catcode`\ß=13
% \defß{\char"FF}
%
\font\test=ecrm1000 \test

Räuber öäüß
\bye
```

[image]

With an utf8 encoded file life gets much more complicated as then you will have to recreate the parsing of the utf8 octets.

### Addition

With the `csplain` or `pdfcsplain` format (http://petr.olsak.net/csplain-e.html) you can use utf8 directly.

```
öäüß

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: The first case breaks the `\uppercase` command, you don't get uppercased accented letters. And the second is interesting because when you write an external file it is written with a different encoding, so a table of contents does not work with that. Any idea on solving that without csplain?

Comment: @BrianMayer: Use latex. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Hahaha never mind, figured that out with [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/the-lowercase-trick). I like minimalistic stuff, plus the nostalgia.

Comment: I don't think "we don't  need such package" is sufficient to avoid the core of question ("an equivalent package...")