# CWEB, Plain TeX: how to switch from cmr8 to another font that supports foreign language characters?

Tags: unicode, plain-tex, cweb

I'm using [egreg's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163852) to use UTF-8 in Plain TeX so I can use Donald Knuth and Silvio Levy's CWEB.  However, not every TeX font supports foreign language characters such as `\"{y}` or `ç` or `ã`.

So this code...

```
\input cwebmac
\input utfplainmac
\input plain-t1

\N{1}{1} Introdução. Lorem ipsum dolor...
```

... produces this result:

[image]

The problem is shown by the log file:

```
Missing character: There is no ç in font cmr8!
Missing character: There is no ã in font cmr8!
```

How could I switch `cmr8` to another font that does have these characters?

Comment: You could try pinging @egreg on that answer so that this gets his attention — there may be a solution without switching away from `cmr8`. (I think this may be something about uppercase... haven't looked deeply.)

Comment: Also, CWEB redefines a bunch of things, and has some strict rules about what can go inside section names... this may be violating some of that. (Have you considered using XeTeX / LuaTeX instead of the above?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define a suitable font for `\eightrm`, but also setup some uppercase conversions; here I define only those necessary for the examples.

There was also an unfortunate typo in `utfplainmac.tex`, with `\c{A}` instead of the correct `\c{C}`. Fix it in the file.

```
\input cwebmac
\input utfplainmac
\input plain-t1

\font\eightrm=ecrm0800

\uccode"A7="87 % ç is <C3><A7>, Ç is <C3><87>
\uccode"A3="83 % ã is <C3><A3>, Ã is <C3><83>

\N{1}{1} Introdução. Lorem ipsum dolor...

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative using `pdfcsplain`:

```
\input cwebmac
\input utf8lat1
\input lmfonts

\N{1}{1} Introdução. Lorem ipsum dolor...

\end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to limbo:

```
\font\eightrm=<your font>
```