# Easy method to activate cyrplain package (CyrTeX)

Tags: packages, plain-tex, cyrillic, format-files, amstex

I would like to have a Cyrillic version of TeX/AMSTeX.  I have installed the [`cyrplain` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/t2/cyrplain/), but further instructions are too long and technical for me, sometimes referring to `README` of other packages or suggesting to manually move some files, and the expected result of following them is not quite clear.  Citing the [README](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/t2/cyrplain/README):

> To install russian support for Plain TeX, AMS-TeX, Texinfo or BLUe
>   TeX, please do the following steps:
>
> 1. To setup hyphenation, you will need russian hyphenation patterns
>      and a file `hyphen.cfg` (either from `BABEL` or created manually). It is
>      recommended to use russian hyphenation patterns contained in the
>      [`ruhyphen`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/language/hyphenation/ruhyphen) package (see the `README` in the parent directory for more
>      information). There you will find also documentation on installation
>      and usage of patterns. Note, that for all Plain TeX-based formats it
>      is recommended to use "combined" Russian-English patterns as a single
>      language to avoid necessity to use language switching commands like
>      `\Russian` and `\English` (you may use a sample "`language.dat`" from the
>      `ruhyphen` package when creating format files).
> 2. If you want to be able to use input encodings other than `cp866`, you
>      should install the [`T2`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/t2) package first. Then edit the file `cyrtex.cfg`,
>      and choose the default input encoding of your documents in the line
>      "`\def\definpenc{koi8-r}`". In this case you must install `BABEL`, because
>      we use some files from `BABEL` (e.g., `plain.def`, `hyphen.cfg`).
>
>    Otherwise (if you will process only documents in `cp866` encoding),
>      change "`\iftrue`" to "`\iffalse`" in `cyrtex.cfg` (or put `cp866` in the
>      definition of `\definpenc`).
>
>    Note that we use here the file `lcydefs.tex` which is part of the
>      `cyrillic` bundle for LaTeX2e (`CTAN:macros/latex/required/cyrillic`).
>      Note that this file should be generated as explained in `00readme.txt`
>      from the `cyrillic` bundle.
> 3. By default, we use `LH` fonts. You could change this to any other
>      `LCY`- or `T2A`-encoded font set (e.g. to use `Type1` virtual fonts like '`C1`
>      fonts package'), by redefining the command `\fontprefix` in
>      `cyrtex.cfg`.
>
>    We support `LCY` and `T2A` font encodings (see `cyrtex.cfg`). If you use `T2A`
>      encoding, you should get `EXMI` fonts from `CTAN:macros/ec-plain/*.mf` and
>      define `\miprefix` to `ex` in `cyrtex.cfg`.
> 4. Edit the file `makefmts.sh` or `makefmts.bat` (depending on your
>      platform), and (optionally) remove or comment out the lines which call
>      `INITEX` for formats which you do not want to install.
>
> Then run the script/batch file `makefmts.sh` or `makefmts.bat`. This
>   will create TeX format files: `cyrtex.fmt`, `cyramstex.fmt`,
>   `cyrtexinfo.fmt` and `cyrblue.fmt` (maybe not all of them if you
>   commented some lines in makefmts script). In case of `makefmts.bat`,
>   we use short DOSish filenames `cyramstx.fmt`, `cyrtxinf.fmt` instead
>   of `cyramstex.fmt`, `cyrtexinfo.fmt`.  You can rename them to long
>   names if your OS supports them. ;-) Finally, install the format files
>   as usual (maybe creating symlinks or scripts/batch files which call
>   TeX with these formats).
>
> Note: if you are using `amsppt` with AMS-TeX, you should also patch
>   the file `amsppt.sty`, changing some hard-coded `CM` fonts to the
>   corresponding cyrillic fonts. The patch `amsppt.diff` is in the `etc`
>   directory of the `T2` package [if you do not have a `patch` utility, you
>   may do the changes manually].

1. Is there an automated method to activate `cyrplain` package (creating `cyrtex.fmt`, `cyramstex.fmt`, ... in some sensible default configuration)?
2. Are there some simpler walk-through instructions than this `README`?
3. (*Soft question.*) The activation seems to affect other packages (for example, patching `amsppt.sty`).  How much will the activation of `cyrplain` affect other parts of the installation?  Can this interference be reduced?

---

In fact, i would not mind any other user friendly solution for being able to compile old sources for russified Plain TeX and AMSTeX, possibly after changing the source encoding. For example, XeTeX looks promising, but i have not yet figured out how to make it use fonts with Cyrillic glyphs. I have created a [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249357/) about Cyrillic XeTeX.

---

### Update

It looks like it should be possible to generate `cyrplain` and `cyramsplain` formats using `fmtutil` and that `fmtutil` already knows about them.

After having patched `/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/plain/cyrplain/plainenc.tex` as suggested in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254098/babel-plain-def-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-yargdef/254125?noredirect=1#comment607367_254125) to the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254098), i tried executing

```shell
sudo fmtutil --enablefmt cyrtex
sudo fmtutil --enablefmt cyramstex
sudo fmtutil --missing
```

and the format files were created in `/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/`.  However, i cannot use them for some reason.  For example,

```shell
tex &cyrtex
```

gives the error:

```
[12] 23093
zsh: command not found: cyrtex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=tex)
**[12]  + suspended (tty input)  tex
```

Very strange, what does `zsh` have to do with it?

Comment: @Igor Could you elaborate your last comment as a different answer? I was arriving at roughly the same conclusion, i.e. use win1251 as input codepage and wcm encoded fonts, so that no reencoding was necessary. To make the answer more spicy, could you show how to make such a format with PDFTeX instead?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko The answer is not really for me, but for Alexey, the OP.

Comment: @Alexey Somehow I have the impression that we didn't actually answer your original question. Do you mind rewriting the question so that the answers actually fit? The point is: there is no easy way to install cyrplain without messing with Plain, LaTeX and Babel at the same time: cyrplain is an adaptation of T2, a LaTeX package, to make it work on Plain; it's rather a kludge anyway.

Comment: I did try using the win1251 codepage input and the wcm fonts from cmcyr, and though it works, it is a nightmare to transfer between machines. So @IgorLiferenko has a better approach with PDFTeX with encTeX enabled, because the input is actually UTF8, which is well supported in modern machines, and the output is the well known xcm encoding, which maps cp866.

Answer (score 3):

There is a format with complete support of russian language in plain TeX at http://github.com/igor-liferenko/tex (it is in file `тех.tex`).

On this site there is also UTF-8 TeX implementation (which passes TRIP test) which allows you to use UTF-8 input directly.

Comment: Where do you get the myplain.ini file? Is that the name of the file you are referring to in the first part of your reply?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that; what I also noticed is that the kernel bash script only assumed the existence of plain.tex and ruhyphal.tex, all other files automagically generated. I'll edit the answer with that information.

Comment: Isn't the lower code packageable into a bash script? That would make the whole process automatic.

Comment: Oh, no! I meant to say that the `cp...texhash` series of commands in the lower part of your answer could be started with a `#!/bin/bash` command, and gathered as a, say, mkmyfmt script.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, thanks for the idea to use encTeX. I'll wait for a more user friendly solution before trying to follow you suggestions. In particular i am not against using XeTeX, but i have not figured out yet how to make it use a font with Cyrillic glyphs.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I stumbled accross a problem: how do you assign the lccodes to the range 128-256 required to make the patterns of hyphru.tex work, if you make the conversion automagically, and the upper and lowercase codes differ between koi8-r and cp866? My inipdftex chokes while trying to process this file and spits a `nonletter` complaint.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Oh! I was trying to test the win1251/wcm setup. I guess I posted in the wrong thread. Sorry!

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, i decided to try your approach, but the command with `perl` that you suggest does not work, even with obvious modifications. Could you tell please what this command does?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, how do i get `myplain` without `perl` command?

Comment: Also it seems that i do not have `hyphru`.

Comment: The instructions assume much more than POSIX, Perl and TeX Live. They assume TeX Live installed in a very particular place, which is typically only true for distro-packages TeX Live on GNU/Linux distros and similar. It isn't true for Mac OS X or upstream vanilla TL.

Comment: Now they just don't mention how specific the instructions are at all! `/usr/local/share/texmf` is not used by upstream TL (including MacTeX). (Or, presumably, Windows.) Is `mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/tex` right? (Trying to guess what `/usr/local/share/texmf` is on your system in terms of the TL trees.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, still using the cmcyr fonts, and assuming you have a cp1251 encoded text file, would be to make a myplain.ini file with only the following commands:

```
\input myplain

\def\set #1 #2 {
  \lccode`#1=`#2
  \lccode`#2=`#2
  \uccode`#1=`#1
  \uccode`#2=`#1
  \catcode`#1=11
  \catcode`#2=11
  \sfcode`#1=999
  \sfcode`#2=1000
}

\set А а
\set Б б
\set В в
\set Г г
\set Д д
\set Е е
\set Ё ё
\set Ж ж
\set З з
\set И и
\set Й й
\set К к
\set Л л
\set М м
\set Н н
\set О о
\set П п
\set Р р
\set С с
\set Т т
\set У у
\set Ф ф
\set Х х
\set Ц ц
\set Ч ч
\set Ш ш
\set Щ щ
\set Ъ ъ
\set Ы ы
\set Ь ь
\set Э э
\set Ю ю
\set Я я

\let\set=\undefined

\input hyphru
\dump
```

Make sure you save this code in cp1251.

And then run the following commands at the bash prompt, or perform similar actions with your OS:

```
cp `kpsewhich plain.tex` myplain.tex
perl -i -ne 'BEGIN{open F,"ls -1 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cmcyr/wcm*|xargs -i basename {} .tfm|";@a=<F>}next if /\\font\\preloaded/;s!(\\font.*?=)(\w+)!$a=$1;$b=$2;$a.(grep(/^x$b/,@a)?"x":"").$b!e; print' myplain.tex
cat `kpsewhich ruhyphal.tex` | iconv -f koi8-r -t cp1251 > hyphru.tex
tex -jobname tex -ini myplain.ini
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/tex/
mv tex.fmt /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/tex/
rm myplain.tex hyphru.tex tex.log
texhash /usr/local/share/texmf
```

Notice that now we are calling the wcm fonts, which are cp1251 encoded, instead of the xcm fonts, which are cp866 encoded, in the perl command; and that we don't need the `-enc` option in the tex call to make the format or the `\mubyte-\endmubyte` pairs, since there is no reencoding needed. In general, if you can match the input and the font encoding of your document, you only need to setup the fonts and hyphenation patterns and they will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i would need to learn a bit about the internal working of TeXLive distribution before following it.