# Troubles with opening a project made in BaKoMa

Tags: errors, input-encodings, font-encodings, bakoma

I've faced the situation where I should open a tex project which consists of a number of chapters and parts. There are a lot of files in a huge number of folders. As I understand they can be compiled separately. Here are the troubles I get trying to open and compile this:

1. When I open these .tex and .sty files I have troubles with encoding. Then I open it in texmaker, which sets the correct encoding but anyway I can't save those files with the changed encoding to open it in texniccenter. What can I do?
2. When I'm trying to compile this, I get some errors, like:

   a. ! Undefined control sequence. \nopagenumbers

   b. ! Font \tensimbol=msxm10 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.\def \def

   c. ! Undefined control sequence.\sectionfootline ->\footline={\ifodd \pageno \rightfootline \else \leftfoot... \sectionfootline

   d. Etc, so the lists of error can be continued.

How is it possible to fix this?

Unfortunately, the text is too long so I can't put down it here. But I dropped a link to rar file with one of the parts.

[Download the rar](https://yadi.sk/d/oK9vsrU8jVSDL)

Answer (score 2):

At first, The document is made using Plain TeX.
Furthermore. It was made using extremely rare bird - Plain TeX with russification.
Finally, such document can't be appeared under BaKoMa TeX.

Important: This document has no any relation to BaKoMa TeX.

Comment: Check this discussion for possible solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248899/easy-method-to-activate-cyrplain-package-cyrtex