# cyrillic (russian) language support in plain tex

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, cyrillic

I started to learn plain-TeX 2 weeks ago and have faced problem with russian language. Is there less painful way to include cyrilic support if I use pdfTex?
I've searched through the site and haven't found expanded answer for pdfTex case, (is this possible at all or should I use something else?).

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use plain TeX? It would certainly be easier to use XeLaTeX, for example.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but non-trivial, but as already commented using a Unicode engine would make life a lot easier. Is there a specific reason to use pdfTeX here for presumably new documents?

Comment: @JosephWright, I have some reason, due to my teacher's task

Comment: @M.Mass Do you mean you've been set this as an assignment?

Comment: @JosephWright, yes

Comment: There are some support files in cyrplain (part of t1): https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/t2/cyrplain. But be aware that the files are from the begin of the century. Why does your teacher gave you this assignment?

Comment: have you seen [this thread](http://bit.ly/2h9qPDN)?

Comment: Are you sure that you've understood the assignment correctly? You are allowed to use neither a different format (LaTeX or ConTeXt) or a modern engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX)?

Comment: To make sure what is the best advice, do you mind telling us what is  your OS and your text's encoding for this task?

Comment: @erreka, that's linux

Comment: But what is your code page/encoding?

Comment: @erreka, utf8 globally

Comment: this is definitely a duplicate of [how to install cyrtex](http://bit.ly/2h9qPDN)

Comment: If you don't need pure TeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249151/70900